# Preventing cereal from writing polymorphic type data

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

I'm using cereal for serialization to a simple packet format for an existing protocol.

However cereal is prefixing the serialized data with portable type information, which I don't want. I don't need to deserialize polymorphic types.

Is there any way to prevent cereal from writing portable type information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found is to create your own serialize functions for shared_ptr / unique_ptr etc.